# How to add an i18n locale prefix in Vue router for all the locales except for the default one?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

I'm trying to create a route to add a locale prefix for all the routes, I got it working using this code:

```js
routes: [{
  path: '/:lang',
  component: {
    template: '<router-view />'
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: 'about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: 'contact',
      name: 'contact',
      component: Contact
    }
  ]
}]
```

For the default locale `en` I don't want to set this prefix so `params.lang` is going to be the full path in this case and not the locale code, so requesting any path without a locale code will render the `Home` component which matches.

So how can I do this? Does a navigation guard like `beforeEnter` help in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can do it without navigation guards. The main goal here is to let the router understand when you have a url without `:lang` parameter. To distinguish between the language prefixes and the actual paths you could use a regex pattern for the `:lang` param like: `(de|fr|en|zu)` (whatever list of codes is suitable for you). And make the `:lang` to be an optional `?`.

So something like this should work: `path: '/:lang(de|fr|en|zu)?'` At least it works for me :) ...

So now if you request `/about` or `/de/about` both would match `About`.. however the first one will have `params.lang` === undefined. So I guess whenever you set your locale you can do: `const locale = this.$route.params.lang || 'en'`

here is the documentation for [Advanced Matching Patterns](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns)

```js
routes: [{
  path: '/:lang(de|fr|en|zu)?',
  component: {
    template: '<router-view />'
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: 'about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: 'contact',
      name: 'contact',
      component: Contact
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that a dynamic parameter can be followed by a regex pattern.

Comment: Glad it helps .. yes the regex with parameters is pretty cool :)